# Graphing and steps calculator

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Is there a calculator which shows graph of a function.
Which also shows calculus(eg integration ) as steps rather then numeric answers ?
Some what some thing like calculator version of wolframalpha.com.

Is there such a thing?

Thank you.

Comment: Smartphones are calculator-sized and can access WA via web

Comment: Probably not. I'm curious - why would you want such a thing? The pictures with steps are a good way to understand the definite integral. But once you have done a few such calculations by hand to learn about them, you should never need to do another.

Comment: I have to write exam in approximation theory. Graphing function helps to start on a problem. But I found graphing degree 4 polynomial hard.
Due to time constrain I wanted calculator with steps.. that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are such tools. Check:

[List_of_computer_algebra_systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems)

Also:

[enter link description here](https://www.symbolab.com)

I personally like Desmos for Graphing:
[Desmos Graphing Calculator](https://www.desmos.com)